# Utility for tile-based map generation

Tags: arrays, dictionary, tile

I started working in a 2D tile-based game, and this is how I'm planning to generate maps:
I have an array with all the tiles in the maps, every element is a integer which represent the tile must be rendered in that position, for instance...

```
int tiles[100] = {
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

};
```

As you can imagine the problem comes with bigger maps, those are only 100 tiles and I'll probably need a few thousands...I can't do it by hand.

So, the question is: Do you guys know some utility which can help me with this?
Some visual tool where i can draw the map and obtain the array?
I'm pretty sure to have seen something like that in the past, sadly I'm unable to find it now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use any graphics editor like GIMP or Paint, then load the resulting image and use the pixel data (for example with a library like [libgd](http://www.libgd.org).

Answer (score 0):

use imagemagick to manage your tilesets
use Tiled to make the arrays (but it  lets you see the arrays visually)

alternative for Tiled is windowsmappy32

don't forget, you can always make your own tool :P